# Make a document look like it's been redacted by the CIA?

Tags: typography

I've produced notes collections for physics courses that I've taken that include problem set solutions.  Two Professors have said they are worried future students will use my notes to cheat (i.e. it's a lot of work to produce new problem sets).  I'm toying with the idea of making the default version for the notes of a couple of these classes a redacted version, with the full version available on request.

I've used a macro around the .tex contents that uses a boolean flag to expand to nothing when a redacted flag is true.  However, I thought there could be a more fun way of doing the same problem.

Is it feasible to make it look like large portions of text (and formulas, and perhaps images) have been gone over by the big black marker of an over-zealous CIA redaction officer, faced with the impossible task of obscuring how much they've spent financing terrorism and government coups around the world?

Here's an example with about 1/3 redaction:

[image: redacted]

If something could be done like this, with random content redacted in black up to some threshold, that would be a pretty fun way of obscuring the problem set solutions.

Comment: There is `censor` package.

Comment: @Werner I don't think this is a duplicate because it wants to randomise the content to be censored. It would, however, definitely benefit from an MWE or some other evidence of what the OP has attempted so far.

Comment: Randomized redaction... that's weird.

Comment: Looks like I can use censor for 100% redaction, but it doesn't like non-text (like \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}.)  I can make my redaction macro include dummy text, instead of my actual content, and then black that out.  Not exactly what I was thinking of, but if it's 100% redacted, perhaps good enough.